# QTreeView not displaying items

Tags: python, pyside

I've created a simple QTreeView widget and I'm subclassing QStandardItemModel but for some reason none of my rows appear to display in the view or print when trying to access it's Data. This seems like a very simple thing. I must be overlooking something in my Model that is making it not work at all. The columns display properly though. I put print statements in the `def data(...)` but they never trigger, why?

[image]

```
import os, sys, datetime
from Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ValidationItem(object):
    def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(ValidationItem, self).__init__()
        self.status = kwargs.get('status', 'info')
        self.message = message


class ValidationItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        super(ValidationItemModel, self).__init__()
        self._items = []
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Status', 'Message'])

    # Overrides
    def clear(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._items = []
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._items)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return self.createIndex(row, column, parent)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        print 'GETTING DATA'
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        print row, col

        item = self.itemByIndex(index.row())
        if not item:
            return None

        print item    
        if role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item

        return None

    # Methods
    def itemByIndex(self, index):
        print index
        if (index < 0 or index >= len(self._items)):
            return None
        return self._items[index]

    def appendItem(self, item):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._items.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()
        print self.rowCount()


class SimpleDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(500,300)

        self.itemModel = ValidationItemModel()
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 1', status='warning'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 2', status='info'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 3', status='error'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 4', status='valid'))
        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.itemModel)

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SimpleDialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATED**

Below is my updated code which I got working. The reason for posting this code, if because a user suggested below that i should be customizable QStandardItem instead of the model. I'm hoping he can demonstrate this with my code so i can better understand on how to do this. The main thing to notice is users can double click an item and it will execute the `run` function of each item accessing it through the UserRole.

[image]

```
import os, sys, datetime
from Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ValidationItem(object):
    def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(ValidationItem, self).__init__()
        self.status = kwargs.get('status', 'info')
        self.message = message

    def run(self):
        print 'STUBBED IN METHOD', self.status, self.message


class ValidationItemURL(ValidationItem):
    def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(ValidationItem, self).__init__()
        self.status = kwargs.get('status', 'info')
        self.message = message

    def run(self):
        os.startfile('https://stackoverflow.com/')



class ValidationItemModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    VALIDATION_STATUSES = {
        'error': QtGui.QColor(220,70,55),
        'warning': QtGui.QColor(240,180,10),
        'valid': QtGui.QColor(10,170,70)
    }


    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        super(ValidationItemModel, self).__init__()
        self._items = []
        self._headers = ['Status', 'Message']

    # Overrides
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._headers[section]

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def clear(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._items = []
        self.endResetModel()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._items)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._headers)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        item = self.itemByIndex(index.row())
        if not item:
            return None

        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                return item.status.title()
            elif column == 1:
                return item.message

        elif role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
            if column == 0:
                return item.status.title()
            elif column == 1:
                return item.message

        elif role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:
            if column == 0:
                if item.status in self.VALIDATION_STATUSES:
                    return self.VALIDATION_STATUSES[item.status]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            return item

        return None

    # Methods
    def itemByIndex(self, index):
        if (index < 0 or index >= len(self._items)):
            return None
        return self._items[index]

    def appendItem(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, ValidationItem):
            self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
            self._items.append(item)
            self.endInsertRows()


class SimpleDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SimpleDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.resize(500,300)

        self.itemModel = ValidationItemModel()
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 1', status='warning'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 2', status='info'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItem('Hello world! 3', status='error'))
        self.itemModel.appendItem(ValidationItemURL('stackoverflow (double-click to visit)', status='valid'))
        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.itemModel)

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Signals
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.slotDoubleClickedItem)


    # Slots
    def slotDoubleClickedItem(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.data(role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            if item:
                item.run()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SimpleDialog()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you get too complicated by modifying the hardest part of the QStandardItemModel? What advantages do you think you will have?

Comment: What do you mean complicated. I'm just subclassing QStandardItemModel... It's common to see this done. So I'm not sure why you think it's the hardest part.

Comment: The reason in doing this is so i can append my own custom class object to the model and anytime a property of my objects change the model will update in real time to reflect those changes made.

Comment: 1) If you want to customize the QStandardItemModel it is advisable only to customize the QStandardItem. It is not necessary to overwrite data methods, etc. since QStandardItemModel is a generic model, unlike abstract classes. 2) For the view to update the model must be notified first, in your case I do not see where you modify your data.

Comment: @eyllanesc You certainly may be right, I've never seen any examples where users have customzied the QstandardItem. I'm completely open to using that as a solution if you would like to demonstrate that. I've update my fulling working code above. It does everything i want it to do. Could you show me what you suggest i do instead of customizing the Model and doing the Item instead.

Comment: Hey @eyllanesc how would i do this by subclassing QStandardItem? I explored ideas but was completely lost when it comes to designing the subclass since my Item displays content in two columns.

Comment: @JokerMartini Your `rowCount()` returns `0` if `parent.isValid()`. Shouldn't it be if **not** `parent.isValid()`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer

The reason your **UPDATED** code works is because *you have implemented* `headerData()`. Per the [Model Subclassing Reference docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) (added emphasis is mine):

> To provide read-only access to data provided by a model, the following functions ***must*** be implemented in the model’s subclass
>
> - `flags()`
> - `data()`
> - **`headerData()`**
> - `rowCount()`
>
> These four functions must be implemented **in all types of model**, including list models (`QAbstractListModel` subclasses) and table models (`QAbstractTableModel`) subclasses.

This is the case even if you do not want headers in your view. To hide them, call `setHeaderHidden(True)` on your `QTreeView` instance.

For doing more than read-only access, the docs go on to state which additional methods must be implemented.

**NOTE:** *My answer references* `PySide6` *, including its documentation and source code. I do not know which python binding or version of* `Qt` *you are using, but my answer should be generally correct.*

---

#### Aside

`@eyllanesc` alluded to the fact that your model must notify the view that it has been updated. The best way to know how and where to do this is by reading the `Qt` C++ source code, but there are also 2 good examples provided by `PySide`:

- [Simple (Ready-Only) Tree Model Example](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel/simpletreemodel.py)
- [Editable Tree Model Example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-6.2/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_editabletreemodel.html)

`QTreeView` is a subclass of `QAbstractItemView`. If you look at the source code for [QTreeView.setModel()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/f53f7095044275767e389d16aabad5ff7144ec9f/src/widgets/itemviews/qtreeview.cpp#L178), you will see it calls [QAbstractItemView.setModel()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/f53f7095044275767e389d16aabad5ff7144ec9f/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L656). Both connect up several sets of signals, but the relevant ones are in `QAbstractItemView`.

`QAbstractItemView` connects the model signals

- `dataChanged()`
- `rowsInserted()`
- `rowsAboutToBeRemoved()`
- `modelReset()`

to view slots of the same name (except for `modelReset()`, the view slot for which is simply `reset()`).

Each of these slots calls `viewport.update()`, which draws the view.

If you look at the source code for [QStandardItemModel](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/845491ed3b38eb756cd73cf4161f440559c9a6a6/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp), you will see

- `insertRows()` calls `rowsInserted`
- `removeRows()` calls `rowsAboutToBeRemoved`
- `setChild()` (and some others) call `dataChanged`

---

**NOTE:** *Any functions used in* `qstandarditemmodel_p.h`, `qstandarditemmodel.h`, *or* `qstandarditemmodel.cpp` *, but not defined there, are defined in* [QAbstractItemModel](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/tree/dev/src/corelib/itemmodels), *(either in one of its header files (as an inline function) or its* `.cpp` *file), since* `QStandardItemModel` *inherits from* `QAbstractItemModel`.

**NOTE:** *C++ allows overloaded functions, whereas Python does not. Instead, in Python, you can specify optional keyword arguments (i.e. those given a default value) to mimic C++ overloading. C++ does not (natively) support keyword arguments.*

*The consequence of this is, when reading the* `Qt` *source, you need to be sure to look at all overloaded methods and choose whether to combine their logic into one method using optional keyword arguments, or use only one of the overloaded methods.*

**NOTE:** `Qt` *practices the* [Pointer to an Implementation, or pIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). *This is a kind of language-specific pattern/technique that removes implementation details of a class from its object representation. You can (loosely) think of it as the C++ version of Python modules. In C++, whenever a translation unit ("file") is modified, it* ***and every other translation unit that uses it*** *must be recompiled. This is an expensive and tedious process, esp. for large code bases, and can cause existing user code linked against it to fail. Using a pointer adds a level of indirection that prevents this from happening. (In Python, every `.py` file is a module and is compiled into byte code (a `.pyc` file) when executed (the bytecode is run by the interpreter). Changing that file causes only that file to need to be recompiled; the rest of your code will still work with it.) In fact* [C++20 finally introduced modules into the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170).

`Qt` *does this by using what it calls* [D-Pointers and Q-Pointers](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer). *The source for these implementation details are placed in* ***private headers*** *suffixed with* `_p.h`. *The names of these classes are suffixed* `Private` *as well.*

*Wherever you see* `d->...`, ***it is using a private class method***. *You can think of* "`d`" *as standing for* ***detail*** *in "implementation detail."*

**WARNING:** *Every method of* `qstandarditemmodel.cpp` *calls* `d->itemFromIndex()`, *which is inlined in* `qstandarditemmodel_p.h`, *but* `qstandarditemmodel.cpp` *also defines its own* `itemFromIndex()` *to be used by model instances. If you do not use the inlined method,* ***your standard item model will not work.***

*Note also that the inlined method returns* `root.data()`, *which is* ***not*** *the same as the model data method.* [`root` is a `QScopedPointer`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5ff637cc140abc07c4c7934fcd6a048a3d0aa66f/src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel_p.h#L212) *of* `QStandardItem`s. *The* [`QScopedPointer.data()` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscopedpointer.html#data) *simply returns the value of the pointer it references, which is the root item. When you see this, simply replace it with your python* `self.root_item`.

*When translating to Python, I recommend creating a pseudo-private (i.e. name-mangled) method* `__itemFromIndex()` *to be used internally in your method implementations, and "public" one* `itemFromIndex()` *to be used externally by instances of your model.*

---

Since `dataChanged` appears to be the only signal exposed in `PySide` (`rowsInserted` and `rowsAboutToBeRemoved` are methods on the private `QStandardItemPrivate` class in C++), the most straightforward solution is to emit `dataChanged` at the end of your `clear()` and `appendRow()` methods (immediately before `endResetModel()` and `endInsertRows()`, resp.).

In general,

- `beginInsertRows()` emits the `rowsAboutToBeInserted()` signal (see [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.beginInsertRows) and [the source](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/39cea8900b02479aca222ba1f4b4bc54a9c27f02/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2880)),
- `endInsertRows()` emits the `rowsInserted()` signal (see [the source](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/39cea8900b02479aca222ba1f4b4bc54a9c27f02/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.cpp#L2896))

and similarly for the corresponding `Columns()` methods.

These should typically be sufficient to update the view, but it's also a good idea to explicitly emit `dataChanged()` when you do so. In fact,  [it should be emitted if `setData()` is successful](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.setData), but the [subclassing docs also state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing):

> The `dataChanged()` and `headerDataChanged()` signals must be emitted explicitly when reimplementing the `setData()` and `setHeaderData()` functions, respectively.